# Problem with CSS Extension in Geoserver 2.7.0

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

I am trying to load the CSS Extension in GS 2.7.0 by unzipping the contents of the archive into the WEB-INF/lib directory in GeoServer. When restarting GS i get a error : "Error creating bean with name "cssDemo" and a 503 Error while open the localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackexchange is not the best place to discuss issues (works better for questions), please report on the geoserver-users mailing list.